# AssertMacros.h: Expected end of line in preprocessor expression

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, xcode5

I recently update my iMac from Mountain Lion OS X 10.8 to Mavericks OS X 10.9,and also updated my Xcode Version 5.0.Now i create project in iOS 7 with cordova 1.7.0 for developing html5 application.When i run my project i got nearly 32 errors in this following header files AsserMacros.h,UIKitDefines.h,CoreFoundation.h,objc.h,stdint.h,secBase.h,CGBase.h,CoreImage.h,CoreVideo.h,CTDefines.h,EAGL.h,yrt-Prefix.pch.Here i attached screen shot for errors.Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks
sas[image]

Comment: Hello.did you solved this error?

Comment: No..Smita i didn't solve this error...

Comment: Actually I faced same issue. And I think this issue is for phonegap's older version. And now I am using latest version without any issue.

Comment: please told about procedure for creating project with using new cordova version

Comment: I follow this [Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS_requirements). It works perfect for me. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks..Smita now it's  work properly.After follow that link.